# When creating an interceptor in angular5, how do I let the request do it's normal thing?

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ErrormodalComponent } from '../../features/errormodal/errormodal.component';
import { UploadComponent } from '../../features/upload/upload.component';


@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _ngbModal: NgbModal) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
      // What to do here?
    }, (err: any) => {
      if(err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
        switch(err.status) {
          case 404:
            // API not found
            console.log('launch')
            this._ngbModal.open(UploadComponent, {size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' })
            break
        }

        console.log('err', err)
      }
    })

  }
}
```

I get the error part, but what do I do where I have `What to do here?` in the event of a normal, non-error request / response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use catch operator instead of do :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HttpResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import {NgbModal} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { ErrormodalComponent } from '../../features/errormodal/errormodal.component';
import { UploadComponent } from '../../features/upload/upload.component';


@Injectable()
export class ErrorInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private _ngbModal: NgbModal) {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).catch((err :  HttpErrorResponse) => {
        switch(err.status) {
          case 404:
            // API not found
            console.log('launch')
            this._ngbModal.open(UploadComponent, {size: 'lg', backdrop: 'static' })
            break
        }

        console.log('err', err);
        return Observable.throw(err);
      });

    }

  }
```

you need to add ErrorInterceptor service to app module providers section like this

```
providers :[
     { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: ErrorInterceptor, multi: true },
]
```

Comment: This says `void is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<HttpEvent<any>>)`

`Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>`

Comment: can you try it after remove switch statement ? may be you got an error but it ;s not related to intercepter service

Comment: I removed the switch altogether, and I'm just logging the `err`. Same issue

Comment: I just make a example for you https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-intercept

Comment: Thanks you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

```
Try something like this:

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

    return next
      .handle(request)
      .map((response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (response instanceof HttpResponse) {

// Here if you want to parse your response you can do it otherwise just let it flow
          return response;
        }
      })
      .catch((response: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        if (response instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {

          return response;
        }
      });
  }
```